# fgets() не ждет ввода с клавиатуры

Tags: c, строки, sqlite3, ввод

Первый ввод `printf("Enter year and press enter: \n");` не ждёт, в связи с чем, добавить туда данные не выходит. Т. е. получается вот так:

```
Enter year and press enter: //1 ввод (невозможен)
Enter sourse and press enter: 
//2 ввод
Enter familia and press enter: 
//3 ввод и т. д.
```

Это рабочий код:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int add(void)
{

    sqlite3 *db;
    
    char *err_msg = 0;

    int rc = sqlite3_open("plants.db", &db);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }

    char sql[1024]; /* make room to hold sql string */

    char year[1024];
    char source[1024];
    char type[1024];
    char familia[1024];
    char taxon[1024];
    char other[1024];

    printf("Enter year and press enter: \n");
        fgets(year, sizeof(year), stdin);
    printf("Enter sourse and press enter: \n");
        fgets(source, sizeof(source), stdin);
    printf("Enter type and press enter: \n");
        fgets(type, sizeof(type), stdin);
    printf("Enter familia and press enter: \n");
        fgets(familia, sizeof(familia), stdin);
    printf("Enter taxon and press enter: \n");
        fgets(taxon, sizeof(taxon), stdin);
    printf("Enter other and press enter: \n");
        fgets(other, sizeof(other), stdin);

    sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO numbers (year, source, type, familia, taxon, other) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');", year, source, type, familia, taxon, other);
        
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);
    
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {

        printf("SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
        
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        
        return 1;
    }
    
    sqlite3_close(db);
    
    printf("Number added!\n");
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Искал решение в сети, но там речь о конфликте `scanf()` и `fgets()`, однако, `scanf()` я не использую, стало быть, дело в другом.

Вылечил вот так:

```
// main.c

...

scanf("%d", &option);

scanf("%*c", &option);

...
```

Вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: Как вы запускаете программу? Замечу что код не рабочий - нет `main`.

Comment: `./main` и далее вызываю функцию через консольное меню. С scanf() всё работает нормально, но там невозможен ввод нескольких слов отбитых пробелами.

Comment: main в файле main :)

Comment: После чтения числа в консольном меню вы не убираете перевод строки. Получается конфликт, о котором вы писали в вопросе.

Comment: Ясно. А как быть? Подскажите пожалуйста на моём примере.

Comment: После ввода в консольном меню прочитать строку `fgets` и выбросить её. Или читать символы до перевода строки и выбрасывать их. Или вообще весь ввод переделать на пары `fgets`/`sscanf` - для интерактивной программы это самый правильный вариант, но он сложный. И наконец, сделать нормальный TUI на curses - но уже совсем по-взрослому.

Comment: `fgets` это буферизованный ввод, и когда вы запускаете программу по Enter, то в буфере остаётся символ, который и принимает первый `fgets`. Чтобы исправить проблему, очистите на входе клавиатурный буфере посредством `fflush` или `flushall`.,

Comment: PRODIGY, спасибо, я примерно представляю, но не разберусь синтаксически и не вполне понимаю, где именно это нужно чистить. Подскажите пожалуйста в коде.

Comment: @PRODIGY, `fflush` не поможет, он работает с выходным потоком. Перевод строки как был в буфере входного потока так там и остался.